# Can I combine files and keep line history

Tags: git

I have a need to combine two files into one. One can simply copy and paste.

However I wonder if git provides any mechanisms so that file combined will keep line history of both files? So when `git blame` you still see histories from both files.

Comment: Just a thought (not sure if it will work) : create a new branch, rename one of the file to match the other, merge the two branches. I think you should keep the line history (except if there are conflicts)

Comment: If I just create a new branch, merging it with the original one would just cause the change to happen. Not sure how to trick Git to merge files.

Comment: After some tests I can't figure out how `git blame` works in presence of `merge` commits. I will look into that further :) My gut feeling is that it's still the best solution you may have though.

Comment: @bperson You were correct. I also came up with this idea before seeing your comment. I have posted a detailed answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: "Try `git blame -C -C -C`.  If that does not already do the job, then no."

The long answer is that if you modify `git blame` itself, you can make this work retroactively, i.e., it will do the trick even for code in which this has already happened.  However, it will take some pretty clever work.

The way `git blame` and `git log --follow` handle file renames is the same as the way `git diff` handles renames and copies, which is to say, via a [heuristic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heuristic).  With `git diff`, you have some control knobs you can use to set the parameters: `-B`, `-M`, `-C`, `--find-copies-harder`, and `-l`.  These allow you to increase and also limit the amount of work `git diff` does in terms of finding copied and moved code.

With `git blame`, you get only the `-C` option, which you can repeat.  (You also get `-M` but it has a different meaning than in `git diff`—diff's rename-detection is turned on as if via the default `-M` option.)

What `git diff`—and therefore `git blame` as well, since it uses the same internal diff machinery—does is to look at each commit as the complete snapshot that it is.

That is, suppose you have (for example) three files total, `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` at the current point in your development.  All three exist now, and you change one (`f1`), add the changes, and commit.  The new commit still has those same three files: it just has a modified version of `f1`, as compared to the previous commit.

If you then remove a file (say, `f3`) and commit, the new commit has two files, `f1` and `f2`.  If you did not modify and `git add` these two files, they are the same in this new commit as they were in the previous commit.  If you *did* modify and `add`—for instance, if you included all of `f3`'s contents into `f2`—then the new commit's remaining files differ from the previous commit's.

What `git diff`, and thus also `git blame`, can do here is to notice that in "previous commit" there were three files, `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, and in "next commit" (or "current commit") there are just two files.  It can therefore look to see if any of the lines of `f3` showed up in either `f1` or `f2`.

If you do the opposite—for instance, if you take some code from any of the files `f1` through `f3` and move it into a new file `f4` and then add and commit these changes—then `git diff` can see that `f4` did not exist before, and does now, so it can look to see if `f4` was renamed or copied from one of the existing files.

In all cases, rename and copy detection can take quite a lot of work.<sup>1</sup>  Hence in the case of `git diff`, rename and copy detection are normally turned off entirely, unless you configure `diff.renames` to `true`,<sup>2</sup> or to `copies` or to `copy`; or if you specify the `-M` and/or `-C` arguments on the command line.  (Git's diff also provides `-l` to set a limit on how hard to look.<sup>3</sup>)

With `git blame`, rename detection is a bit easier as it works on just one file at a time (capturing renames automatically with an effective `-M50%`).  The difficulties crop up only for detecting copied lines.  Here, `-C`—given once—tells `git blame` to look at files that were modified (including deletion) in the *same* commit that modified the file being examined.  Given twice, `git blame` will look at files modified in the same commit at the point the file was created.  Given three times, `git blame` will look at all files in each commit.  That is, even if `f1` is unchanged in a commit where you've asked `git blame` to look at a change to file `f3`, it will look for copies from `f1`, but only if you've given `-C` three times.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's one case of rename/copy detection that is very easy due to git's design.  A file that is *exactly* the same as some other file has the same "internal name" inside git's repository, as the "name" of a repository object is actually just a cryptographic checksum of the object's data.  Git assumes that no two different files will ever checksum to the same value.

It's theoretically possible that this will go wrong.  The chances are given by the ["Birthday problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem).  Since SHA-1 is a 160-bit hash, the chance of any two files randomly colliding is 1 out of 2<sup>159</sup>, or 1 out of 730 750 818 665 451 459 101 842 416 358 141 509 827 966 271 488 (about 1 out of 730 [quindecillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) in the "short scale" system).  It's not that big a concern; we're more likely to be wiped out by an errant asteroid. :-)

<sup>2</sup>Set to any valid boolean "true", really.  See the documentation for [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

<sup>3</sup>This is configurable as `diff.renameLimit`.  Set to `0` it means "no limit".  The default has evolved over the years; it was 100, then 200, and is currently set to 400.  I believe the existing limits have no real effect on `git blame`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this! Say you have two files `foo` and `bar` that you wish to merge to `foobar`:

1. Create branch `my_branch`.
2. Checkout branch `my_branch`, rename `foo` to `foobar`, commit.
3. Checkout branch `master`, rename `bar` to `foobar`, commit.
4. Now merge `my_branch` into master. You will get a big conflict. Resolve it and commit.
5. Profit!

I just now needed to do this and it works great!

(Note that @bperson suggested this above already)